# Image in drawable but still getting error

Tags: android, xml, imageview, drawable

So I keep running into this error for my
[ImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yCOf.png) even though I have copy/pasted the image into my [drawable folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGMBW.png) and have called it in my ImageView XML Code:

```
    <ImageView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/home_screen" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to clean / rebuild

Comment: Did my answer work for you? @Jordan

Comment: Just adding to the answer. The resource file name should start with a letter. This was the error in mine

Answer (score 3):

Your drawable document would be in v24 drawable file. Move it to normal drawable file. You can move in project section.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing appears to be wrong so try to rebuild and refresh your project. Maybe close and reopen your android studio.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see nothing is wrong with your code, so try those steps that I give to you:

1.- Remove the home_screen.png from your `Drawable` folder.

2.- Clear / rebuild project ( even if you want you can restart your IDE )

3.- Try it again, copy and paste the image to your `Drawable` folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this could help you, but once it happens to me.
IDE wasn't showing an error that I did when wrote one *Class*. After reading the whole code, I could found and fix it.

After that *R* class was updated and the resource was found.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all xml style docs. And add again xml docs. But create new drawable file. And don't copy paste xml file. just add new drawable file. I fixed this issue this metod.

Answer (score 0):

File name in the drawable folder in android studio. Must follow the below naming convention. After changing capital letters to small letters to my file name. it resolved the problem

File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore